# What's the [force-download] tag for?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

I'm not entirely sure what the [force-download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/force-download) tag is actually useful for. I guess that it is for "forcing" something to download, but this is used for all kinds of things, and kind of useless.

Should it be burninated ?

Comment: Quite simple, it's for aspiring yedi which don't have that neccessary upgrade yet.

Comment: @Deduplicator very surprised, of such methods, I am.

Comment: We should have a tag wiki. A short one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The questions in [force-download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/force-download) seem to mostly involve [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) users who cannot figure out how to set the `Content-Type` of their page to `application/octet-stream` and set the downloaded file name.

The top five questions (by votes):

- [PHP create file for download without saving on server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5560373/359284)
- [force download using ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15219873/359284)
- [Idiot-proof, cross-browser force download in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2222955/359284)
- [Force Downloading a PDF file, corrupt file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15889557/359284)
- [How to force download of big files without using too much memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6195550/359284)

Now, most questions that I saw (after briefly looking through the list) appeared to be asking about forcing a file to be downloaded instead of streaming it.

---

So, let's answer the questions from [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/159034):

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

While the tag is lacking any wikis, I would say that the questions under the tags are for situations involving forcing a download ("Save file to...") dialog to appear instead of returning a standard request. The tag name is pretty clear and appears to fit the collection of questions well.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes. Determining how to fix an issue with their logic is on topic for the site.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Now this is always the debatable question. Some would say that trying to force a response to be downloaded instead of streamed is a common enough issue that it deserves its own tag. Others would say that the issues tend to revolve around a few central issues, and it would be better combined into a single FAQ-style post that could be used as a duplicate target.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

There appears to be two distinct situations where this tag is used.

1. Someone is trying to serve a file and wants it to be force-downloaded.
2. Someone has a file on the client side (JS + Canvas, usually) and wants to have the file be downloaded and saved locally, similar to how it would be done if a server was generating the file.

---

So do I think we should burninate it? **No.** It has a somewhat clear meaning, it is on-topic for the site, and nobody appears to be using the tag for their force-downloading plugin that they developed.

But maybe it should be cleaned up? **Definitely.** A lot of the questions are some variation of "I copied this PHP code that doesn't work, why?" and I think they could be combined into a central duplicate target. Making a file be downloaded instead of streamed by a browser can be tricky, and most of the questions share a few common problems.

Comment: Are you implying that we should use [can't-figure-how-php-works] tag?

Comment: Okay, But it needs a tag wiki at least. Nice answer !